mathematical notation of a product of n-uplet elements
I have the following $n$ sets:
$A_{1}=\{A_{1}^{1}, A_{1}^{2}, ... , A_{1}^{j_1}\}$ ;
$A_{2}=\{A_{2}^{1}, A_{2}^{2}, ... , A_{2}^{j_2}\}$ ; ...
$A_{n}=\{A_{n}^1, A_{n}^{2}, ... , A_{n}^{j_n}\}$.
Let $m=\prod_{k=1}^{n} j_k$.
How do I express generally a product of $n$-uplet elements given that each $n$-uplet must contain an element of each set.  
Example: Let $n=3, j_1=2, j_2=3, j_3=1$, there are 6 products: $A_{1}^{1}.A_{2}^{1}.A_{3}^1, A_{1}^{1}.A_{2}^{2}.A_{3}^1, A_{1}^{1}.A_{2}^{3}.A_{3}^1, A_{1}^{2}.A_{2}^{1}.A_{3}^1, A_{1}^{2}.A_{2}^{2}.A_{3}^1, A_{1}^{2}.A_{2}^{3}.A_{3}^1$ 
So I want to find how to write one such product mathematically?

@AnneBauval Thanks. would it be correct to call it $p_l= \prod_{i=1}^n A_i^{k_i}$ where $ l$ is between 1 and m?

@AnneBauval Thanks again. They are functions

Such a product can be written
$$p_\ell:=\prod_{k=1}^nA_k^{\ell(k)},\quad \ell\in\prod_{k=1}^n\{1,\dots,j_k\}$$
or simply
$$p_F:=\prod_{k=1}^n F(k),\quad F\in\prod_{k=1}^nA_k.$$
Edit (to answer the comment): Let $L:=\prod_{k=1}^n\{1,\dots,j_k\}$ (so, $|L|=m$). Then, the sum of all products $p_\ell$ is
$$\sum_{\ell\in L}p_\ell=\sum_{\ell\in L}\prod_{k=1}^nA_k^{\ell(k)}=\prod_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j_k}A_k^i.$$

Is the sum of all terms written as $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \prod_{k=1}^{n} A_k^{l(k)} , \ l \in \prod_{k=1}^n {1, \cdots, j_k}$ and $m=\prod_{k=1}^n j_k $?  (implying that $p_l$ could be rewritten as $p_i$). Thanks.

How is  $A_1^1A_2^1A_3^1c^1+A_1^1A_2^2A_3^1c^2+A_1^1A_3^1A_3^1c^3+\cdots + A_1^2A_2^3A_3^1c^6$ written? Please generalize the above formula to arbitrary $n$ and not simply $n=3$. It is not $c^k$.  I have the following info. that is perhaps useful: For an $n-$tuple given by $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$, the lexicographical position is given by: $p=1+\sum_{k=1}^n [(x_k-1)\prod_{k'=1}^{k-1} j_{k'}]$. I can perhaps use $c^{ p}$ but how about $x_k$? thanks
